# Facebook api delete Event not working a 100%

Tags: facebook, api, events

I am developing a website that uses facebook api to create events. If the user decides they want to delete the event again, they can do so which works fine with my website, meaning the event will also be deleted on facebook. So far so good. But the user can also use an already (via facebook.com) created event and link it to the event created on my website. When the user deletes that event, the event on facebook is not deleted. 
Is that a security mechanism or do I have the access rights wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to delete events your application didn't create, what API calls are you using and what error messages are you receiving when you try?

Comment: I used the php sdk and sent a DELETE request with the event id and the access_token as parameters. Havent really checked the response to be honest.